# onSuccess - Asynchronous Http Client

Tags: android, android-async-http

I'm using the [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). My code looks like this and is working fine.

```
    DataUtil.post("RegisterUser", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
        public void onSuccess(String answer) {              
            // initialize variables
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            String message = null;

            try {
                // turn string into JSONObject
                json = new JSONObject(answer);
                message = json.getString("message");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }

            // registration was successful
            if (message.equals("success")) {
                // forward to login page      
            } else {
            // error
            }
        }
    });
```

I implemented a [static HTTP Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/#recommended-usage-make-a-static-http-client). My server returns this JSON data `{"message":"success"}`. I do not want to treat it as a String and cast it back to JSON. But when I change it to `public void onSuccess(JSONObject answer)` eclipse tells me

> The method onSuccess(JSONObject) of type new
>   AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){} must override or implement a supertype
>   method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct method signature would be this `public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response)` or any of the other available methods in the [`JsonHttpResponseHandler`](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/JsonHttpResponseHandler.java) class